# at a time only one check box should be selected in a particular row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview. It has 2 columns which are of type boolean. Now what I want to do is, when I click on one checkbox the other check box in the same row should be unchecked. that is, at a time only one check box should be selected in a particular row. The user should not be able to select the 2 check boxes together.

How can I achieve this ? I tried using cellcontentclick and cellcontentChanged events. nothing works.

any inputs ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use CellEndEdit Event or      CellLeave event

when ever you will leave the cell after doing edits this event will fire.
In the following snippet Column1 is your first checkbox and Column2 is your other checkbox.

```
       private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column1"].Value))
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column2"].Value = false;
        }
```

Comment: I didn't get the desired output with the above code. When I check column one, if column 2 is already checked it should get unchecked. But the code doesn't work as expected

Comment: please move your cursor to some other column and then check. i have tested this code and is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use **DataGrid_CellEditEnding**

In that iterate through DataSource, if u find any checked colum (`boolean true`) make it unchecked (`boolean false`).
hope it will help u

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
         foreach (var Item in dataGridView1.ItemsSource)
         {
             if(Item.isChecked) 
                 Item.isChecked = false;
         }
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column1"].Value))
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column2"].Value = false;
    }
```